# editor.tokenColorCustomizations, how do I change docstrings size for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I would like to change the font size of docstrings when editing Python code. I currently use this setup:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[*]": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#413f3f",
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
         }]
     }
}
```

Is there any way to specify the font size as well? It would be helpful if the font size had a relative size to the main font (because I often use to resize font).

Comment: you can try to use **CC Inject** extension, find the CSS selector of your docstrings and use it to change the font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, the font size of some specific fragments in the code cannot be modified.

There are all font size on the following settings to modify the editing page.

```
    "editor.fontSize": 20,
```

Search `fontSize` on the **Settings** panel to find more settings.

[image]

You can continue to pay attention to this feature request and express your will in it.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36512